# Cannot add text on repeated bar graphs - Altair

Tags: python, altair, graphing

I created a repeated bar graph with altair but I cannot seem to add the same text (column = Rank) to the bars on all bar charts. This is the error message I get: 'RepeatChart' object has no attribute 'mark_text'

```
chart1 = alt.Chart(merged, width=500, height=300).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X("City", type='ordinal', sort="-y"),
    alt.Y(alt.repeat("column"), type='quantitative'),
    alt.Color('City', legend=None, scale=alt.Scale(scheme='tableau20'))).repeat(
    column=['Cost of a bottle of water(City)', 'Pollution(Index score) (City)', 'Annual average hours worked', 
            'Outdoor activities(City)','Number of take out places(City)', 'Cost of a monthly gym membership(City)', 
            'Cost of Living Index', 'Rent Index', 'Cost of Living Plus Rent Index', 'Groceries Index', 
            'Restaurant Price Index','Local Purchasing Power Index'])
chart1  

text = chart1.mark_text(baseline='middle',
    dx=20,
    angle=340,
    color='black',
).encode(
    text=alt.Text('Rank'))

chart1 + text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the mark of a RepeatChart. You need to create the layer first and then use repeat on the layered chart. Something like this:

```py
chart1 = alt.Chart(merged, width=500, height=300).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X("City", type='ordinal', sort="-y"),
    alt.Y(alt.repeat("column"), type='quantitative'),
    alt.Color('City', legend=None, scale=alt.Scale(scheme='tableau20')))

text = chart1.mark_text(baseline='middle',
    dx=20,
    angle=340,
    color='black',
).encode(
    text=alt.Text('Rank'))

(chart1 + text).repeat(
    column=['Cost of a bottle of water(City)', 'Pollution(Index score) (City)', 'Annual average hours worked', 
            'Outdoor activities(City)','Number of take out places(City)', 'Cost of a monthly gym membership(City)', 
            'Cost of Living Index', 'Rent Index', 'Cost of Living Plus Rent Index', 'Groceries Index', 
            'Restaurant Price Index','Local Purchasing Power Index'])
```

Here is a complete reproducible example:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data


source = data.cars()


c = alt.Chart(source).mark_circle().encode(
    x=alt.X('Weight_in_lbs:Q', title=''),
    y=alt.Y(alt.repeat(), type='quantitative'),
)

(c + c.mark_line()).repeat(['Horsepower', 'Acceleration'])
```

[image]

Comment: I tried it and I still get the same error: RepeatChart' object has no attribute 'mark_text' . :(

Comment: @SarahAbdelazim I just added a complete example where you can see how this works. You should be able to copy/paste that into your notebook, let me know if it doesn't work. In general it is a good idea to create a [mre] using sample data from vega_datasets when asking question so that there are not any errors specific to your data or when copy pasting.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! Do  you mind showing me how to do add regression lines for my repeated scatter plots as well? I edited my first comment to include that

Comment: @SarahAbdelazim Please open a new question for that with an example and I will take a look. You can mark this question as resolved with the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: Ideally include a dataset in your question, such as in my example with the cars data.

Comment: Here's the link to my new question! https://stackoverflow.com/q/72004738/18914126 .  Thanks a lot for your help!